# Can not record during calls

Tags: android, react-native, audio-recording, android-audiorecord

I'm using React Native to implement an Android app that helps us record outgoing calls.
After the user types a phone number and clicks `call`, I start Recorder and then navigate the user to the phone screen to make a call.

The issue is that I only record voice before and after the user dials. nothing during the call.

I tested on a Nokia C31 (android 12)

here is my code.

```js
import AudioRecorderPlayer, {
  AudioEncoderAndroidType,
  AudioSet,
  AudioSourceAndroidType,
} from 'react-native-audio-recorder-player';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';
const dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;

const audioSet: AudioSet = {
  AudioEncoderAndroid: AudioEncoderAndroidType.DEFAULT,
  AudioSourceAndroid: AudioSourceAndroidType.VOICE_COMMUNICATION,
};

export default function Dialer() {
  // other states...
  const audioRecorderPlayer = useRef(new AudioRecorderPlayer());

  const startRecording = async () => {
    const formattedDate = dayjs().format('DD-MMM-YYYY_hh-mm-ss-A');
    const fileName = `${dirs.CacheDir}/call-record_${formattedDate}.mp3`;
    console.log(fileName);
    setAudioPath(fileName);
    try {
      setIsRecording(true);
      const result = await audioRecorderPlayer.current.startRecorder(
        fileName,
        audioSet,
        true,
      );
      console.log('start recording', result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error starting recording:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleCall = () => {
    if (!isRecording) {
      startRecording();
      console.log('called');
      Linking.openURL(`tel:${number}`);
    }
  };
//...
}
```

permissions requested

```js
const permissions = [
  PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
  PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
  PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECORD_AUDIO,
  PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CALL_PHONE,
];
```

here is my manifest

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT" />
```

I think I need to use the VOICE_CALL instead of VOICE_COMMUNICATION.

but VOICE_CALL needs `android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT`.

according to the documentation:
`This permission is reserved for use by system components and is not available to third-party applications.`

when I use VOICE_CALL, I can not start the Recorder (get error)

Comment: I think this is why rooting was done

Comment: @FaysalB, no I can not root devices.

Answer (score 1):

Only system apps can use VOICE_CALL.  This is for security reasons.  Android does not allow any app to get the audio of a call, except for preinstalled apps from the OEM.  The only way you can record a call as an app on Android is to use the normal microphone and hope the volume of the call is loud enough that it gets picked up.

Comment: but according to [this documents](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/platform/sharing-audio-input#voice_call_ordinary_app), if we create an AccessibilityService we can get the voice call audio, right?

Comment: If you're not actually providing accessibility, then you won't be allowed to use an AccessibilityService.  The Play store rejects any app that uses that permission inappropriately.

Comment: Also, from my reading of that, it can receive audio input.  That means that it will allow you to process input from the mic, and would still need the special permission to receive call audio even as an accessibility service.  This seems mainly used to allow such services to process voice commands also sent to the app.  Although I haven't tested, so maybe it would attempt to allow it for transcription purposes.

Comment: did you do this feature before? is there any other way to do that? I just want to save my agents's calls for management

Comment: I haven't.  But I can tell you that the Play Store will absolutely not allow you to use AccessibilityService to save calls for management.  If this is side loaded that's fine, but if it's downloaded from the Play Store it's going to be a blocker.